# Listbox Selection Change Event Selected Index

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I am new to web building.  I have the following listbox on the page.  The page is enabled view state.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ExamsList_ListBox" runat="server" DataTextField="Namee" viewstate="enabled"
            DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true" Height="213px" Width="152px" 
            ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

The data is data bind at run time.  I ma able to see the list, but the listbox.selectedindex always results in "-1" value only even though I click the 10th one in box.  could you please tell me what is wrong.

Here is the page code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body >
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ExamsList_ListBox" runat="server" DataTextField="Namee" viewstate="enabled"
            DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="true" Height="213px" Width="152px" 
            ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code for filling in data is :

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If IsNothing(CType(Session("Login"), TikoClasses.Login)) Then
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx")
        ElseIf (CType(Session("Login"), TikoClasses.Login)).Admin = False Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Loggedin/Welcome.aspx")
        End If
        ExamsList_ListBox.DataSource = DataModule.Exams_listall((CType(Session("Login"), TikoClasses.Login)).Inst_ID)
        ExamsList_ListBox.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

and selection changed even is:

```
Try
            Dim k As Integer = ExamsList_ListBox.SelectedIndex
            Dim tt As List(Of Integer) = ExamsList_ListBox.GetSelectedIndices.ToList
            Dim t As Object = ExamsList_ListBox.SelectedValue
            If ExamsList_ListBox.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
                DataModule.GetExam(CType(Session("Login"), TikoClasses.Login).Inst_ID, ExamsList_ListBox.SelectedValue)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Looking for help.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your bind code under `!IsPostBack`

```
if(!IsPostBack)
   ExamsList_ListBox.DataSource = DataModule.Exams_listall((CType(Session("Login"), TikoClasses.Login)).Inst_ID)
   ExamsList_ListBox.DataBind()
Endif
```

Since whenever your selection is Changed, your page_load event fired first and your selection is lost.

Comment: So where should I keep the this code, is it in page load event?

Comment: yes, that should be in page load event, but under !IsPostBack condition.

Comment: It is still the same.  I changed the Page load event to this: Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If (Not IsPostBack) Then
            ExamsList_ListBox.DataSource = DataModule.Exams_listall((CType(Session("Login"), TikoClasses.Login)).Inst_ID)
            ExamsList_ListBox.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub     By this code, It is firing with 0 index as result only.